# How to implement stream with skip and conditional stop

Tags: akka-stream

I try to implement batch processing. My algo:

1) First I need request items from db, initial `skip = 0`. If no items then completely stop processing.

```
  case class Item(i: Int)

  def getItems(skip: Int): Future[Seq[Item]] = {
    Future((skip until (skip + (if (skip < 756) 100 else 0))).map(Item))
  }
```

2) Then for every item do heavy job (`parallelism = 4`)

```
  def heavyJob(item: Item): Future[String] = Future {
    Thread.sleep(1000)
    item.i.toString + " done"
  }
```

3) After all items processing, go to 1 step with `skip += 100`

Whats I trying:

```
val dbSource: Source[List[Item], _] = Source.fromFuture(getItems(0).map(_.toList))

val flattened: Source[Item, _] = dbSource.mapConcat(identity)

val procced: Source[String, _] = flattened.mapAsync(4)(item => heavyJob(item))

procced.runWith(Sink.onComplete(t => println("Complete: " + t.isSuccess)))
```

But I don't know how to implement pagination

Comment: Will the stream continue to increment `skip` or are the `0` & `100` values the only inputs used?

Comment: Yes, it will increment by 100 every iteration

Comment: Also, does the rule "if no items then stop processing" apply to each iteration of the `skip` increment?  e.g. if skip is at `800` and no items are returned should the processing stop?

Comment: Yes, it should stop(no more record in database).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `skip` incrementing can be handled with an `Iterator` as the underlying source of values:

```
val skipIncrement = 100

val skipIterator : () => Iterator[Int] = 
  () => Iterator from (0, skipIncrement)
```

This Iterator can then be used to drive an akka `Source` which get the items and will continue processing until a query returns an empty `Seq`:

```
val databaseStillHasValues : Seq[Item] => Boolean = 
  (dbValues) => !dbValues.isEmpty

val itemSource : Source[Item, _] = 
  Source.fromIterator(skipIterator)
        .mapAsync(1)(getItems)
        .takeWhile(databaseStillHasValues)
        .mapConcat(identity)
```

The `heavyJob` can be used within a `Flow`:

```
val heavyParallelism = 4

val heavyFlow : Flow[Item, String, _] = 
  Flow[Item].mapAsync(heavyParallelism)(heavyJob)
```

Finally, the Source and Flow can be attached to the `Sink`:

```
val printSink = Sink[String].foreach(t => println(s"Complete: ${t.isSuccess}"))

itemSource.via(heavyFlow)
          .runWith(printSink)
```